# C# - Determining responsibility between GUI and logic class

Tags: c#, design-patterns, user-interface

I have a form and a logic class. Based on user actions, the class generates a list of actions. These actions then need to be displayed as buttons on the form, so the user can select from them.
My initial solution was this:

```
public class Logic {
    public List<string> GetActions() {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        // ...prepare list
        return result;
    }
}

public class FrmGUI : Form {
    Logic logic = new Logic();
    private void PopulateButtons() {
        foreach(string action in logic.GetActions(){
            //...create button
        }
    }
}
```

The GUI retrieves the list of strings from the Logic class and then uses that to populate a panel with buttons. Now supposedly this is bad OO practise because I'm exposing something about how Logic class behaves. There is an assumption here that the GetActions method will always exist and that the Logic class will always be able to return this list of strings.

Another solution is this:

```
public class Logic {
    public void PopulateButtons(Panel panel, Action<object, EventArgs> eventHandler) {
        // ...prepare list
        // ...populate buttons
    }
}

public class FrmGUI : Form {
    Logic logic = new Logic();
    private void PopulateButtons() {
        logic.PopulateButtons(this.panel1, actionButtonClickHandler);
    }
}
```

Now here the GUI class knows nothing about the logic class and only expects to get the buttons populated. On the other hand, the logic class is now involved in GUI stuff.

What is the correct way to handle such cases. Or is there a third implementation which is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend placing a layer of abstraction between your `Logic` and your `FrmGUI`.

For a simplistic example, let's say you have a login in you application.  Define an interface for your **logical** screen.  Note there is no mention here of what controls are used.  The Logic classes never knows the UI class/form used.

```
interface ILoginScreen : IScreen
{
   event EventHandler LoginInvoked;
   event EventHandler CancelInvoked;

   string User { get; set; }
   string Password { get; set; }   
}
```

In your LoginLogic class you have code like this:

```
void Start() // initial LoginLogic method
{

   ILoginScreen loginScreen = uiFactory.CreateLoginScreen();

   loginScreen.User = string.empty;
   loginScreen.Password = string.empty;

   loginScreen.LoginInvoked += new EventHandler(LoginScreen_LoginInvoked);
   loginScreen.CancelInvoked += new EventHandler(LoginScreen_CancelInvoked);

   loginScreen.Show();

}

void LoginScreen_LoginInvoked(s, e)
{
   if (ValidateCredentials(loginScreen.User, loginScreen.Password))
   {
      // goto the next screen logic controller
   }
}
```

In your form, you implement ILoginScreen and refresh the UI fields with data from teh USer and Password properties.  Additionally, you raise the required Login and Cancel events based on the user feedback (button click, Escape keystroke, whatever).

While this is a simplistic example, I do a lot of Windows Mobile and Windows CE apps where it is very common to want to run the same application on vastly different form-factors OS variants and this approach lets you literally snap on new GUI form-factors.  The heart of that usage is the UIFactory that is dynamically loaded to provide the appropriate UI implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the former patttern: The Logic-layer creates information, and UI-layer uses that information to create the UI.

That way, if you decide to re-skin the UI to use a drop-down list of items you only have to change the UI layer, not the logic.

It means that the UI layer has a minimal dependency on the types/data provided by the logic layer (as long as it doesn't know anything about how the logic is implemented, that is fine), but the logic layer has no idea whatsoever about what the UI implementation is - which is what you want (the lower level components in a system should not know anything about the higher level design, while the higher level components must necessarily have a basic understanding of the low-level components that they utilise).

It would be preferable that the application (or some other external entity) creates both the Logic and UI and links them together, rather than the UI itself creating the Logic - this will help the UI and logic to be much more loosely coupled.

Answer (score 1):

That `Logic` can report the actions it supports (1st pattern) looks fine to me (but the return type of `GetActions` really should be `IEnumerable<string>` instead of a list).

Not so good is that in your sample the form instantiates the `Logic` class directly. Typically, you'd create an interface or abstract base class for the different types of `Logic` classes that you might have, and have concrete implementations fill in the functionality. The form would then get the logic to use through some [inversion-of-control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

correct????? Over the years lots of people have invested lots of time in trying standardise this approach and I'm afraid the answer may be deduced from the number of ui design patterns out there!

You may want to look at MVC, MVP, MVVM patterns, all of which are in vogue at the moment.

In general:

it is a good idea to try to split logic from presentation, so you're on the right lines. But remember that one of the consequences of this split is that it is better for your "logic" not to know anything about presentation (since you already have a class responsible for that).

So you might want to think about the concept of "buttons", and think (from your logic point of view), "don't I really mean commands?". They only really become buttons when you think of them in the context of a screen. But, say, a command to load the transactions on a particular bank account....you don't need a screen to conceptualise how this would work.

A good thing I find is to imagine that you're going to develop this app with both a forms front end and, say, a web front end which does exactly the same thing. Obviously these two apps would have a totally different presentation layer because of the fundamentally different technologies involved.

But because you don't want to write code twice you'll have a "logic" layer too, where you'll stuff as much common code as you can. For example, deciding whether a bank account is overdrawn - doesn't matter whether you're web or win, overdrawn is still overdrawn. And conversely, any place where you'd end up writing different code between web and win belongs into your "presentation" layer. For example, displaying an overdrawn balance in red.

Food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

the first one is better, because your interface between GUI and logic is just a list of string.
After, it all depends on the way you're calling actions on your logic class from your button.
If you have a generic method taking the action string, it's fine. If you need to call different methods on your logic class depending on the action string, you'll need a mapping in the GUI class to map action string and method call. you could also import this "action string - mapping method" from your logic class to keep things separated.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is, it depends on the reason for creating something like a logic tier and a GUI tier. I think the most common reason is to reuse the logic, e.g. to use it for a WPF and a web GUI, or the data has to be processed before sending it to the GUI. Your first example fits the mentioned pattern. In your second example the logic seems not to be reuseable, because its gui specific. 
However, in the real world there it right or wrong answer. The architecture should fit your needs and make your project maintainable(e.g. by reduce redundant code).
In your case the question is: How often do you need these functions and where/when do you need them?